# INTERSECT in ORACLE (SQL not PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to do `INTERSECTION` in between two select statements. The condition is intersection should take place only when both the select statements return some resultset. If any of the ones returns O rows Intersection should not work and the final result must be of the statement which has returned some rows. Is this possible in `SQL`(I do not need the answer in `pl/sql`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using this construction.

```
with t1 as (select level id from dual where 1 = 0 connect by level <= 3),
     t2 as (select level id from dual where 1 = 1 connect by level <= 5)
select distinct * 
  from t1 
  where exists (select null from t2 where id = t1.id)
    or (select count(1) from t2) = 0
union all
select distinct * from t2 where (select count(1) from t1) = 0
```

`t1` and `t2` simulates some data. First `select` makes intersection or gets all distinct rows from first table if there is no data in `t2`. 
Second `select` (after `union all`) is to get all data from `t2` if there are no rows in `t1`.

**Edit:** You can do it simplier:

```
select * from t1 
intersect 
select * from t2 
union 
select * from t1 where (select count(1) from t2) = 0
union 
select * from t2 where (select count(1) from t1) = 0
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. This is a perfect solution with very well explanation. It worked for me.Thanks alot :-)